# How to do client-server over the internet

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, client-server

We want to create apps that connects to our database (Sybase ADS, connectable via .NET) over the Internet. The clients will include a windows forms app and probably an android app for phones and devices.

I know C#. I'm new to Web apps and webservices so bear with me here.

I'm thinking maybe the best way is creating a webservice in C# to run on IIS that will interrogate the ADS database using ADO.net.

So the webservice will expose methods via WCF that can be consumed by the clients.

The clients then invoke the methods via WCF. Am I right in thinking WCF will return data in .net XML objects?

Also can .net Forms consume XML objects easily?

The apps would have bespoke restricted access using credentials.

How does this approach sound? Any performance or security issues to think about? The data is not exactly classified but I wouldn't want snoopers to be able to pick up phone numbers etc.

Can most security be sorted out by just going from http to https?

What about performance. Presumably slower than if the apps were just connected using ADO.net to ADS on the LAN. Does WCF use bufers for http requests?
E.g. can you can start reading the stream on the client before the whole http request has finished? I'm thinking for populating list boxes of large record nos. etc

Comment: With Web services (good approach), XML, communications requests and objects serialization are used internally but are hidden to application level, i.e. methods call. FYI, you can implement web services without IIS.

Comment: Thanks Graffiti.  I read a bit more about WCF and yes I can creste the server or "host" as a windows service. Don't need IIS.